# Syntax error while trying to install PyInstaller

Tags: python, pip, pyinstaller

I'm trying to install the python package, pyinstaller using pip. However, I am encountering this problem:

[image]

Comment: You have outdated `win32ctypes`. Remove it.

Comment: thanks for the advice, will be more considerate in the future. By the way, I have solved the problem by switching to python 3.6.